# is that possible to make MongoDB in mongoose as RealTime Database like Firebase?

Tags: database, mongodb, sockets, mongoose, socket.io

is that possible to make mongoDB as Real time database ? I read that mongoDB has `watch()` method but I am not sure how to implementation it on Mongoose, I am using MongoDB Atlas

if I watch one `Model/collection`, would it be real time to update/get/add ? like **firebase** do ??
is there any example for `crud` with watch ? for express based and mongoose ??

I really want to know this because I have a small project to build e-commerce website, so when in the client Add to cart, they could update and remove in real time on MongoDB, so I was thinking that it would be work with `MongoDB Watch()`, Is that correct??